# How to display subversion URL for the Project with jenkins email-ext plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jelly, email-ext

Here is the jelly script i am using:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">
  <STYLE>BODY, TABLE, TD, TH, P { font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,sans serif; font-size:11px; color:black; } h1 { color:black; } h2 { color:black; } h3 { 
color:black; } TD.bg1 { color:white; background-color:#0000C0; font-size:120% } TD.bg2 { color:white;
  background-color:#4040FF; font-size:110% } TD.bg3 { color:white; background-color:#8080FF; } TD.test_passed { color:blue; } TD.test_failed { color:red
; } TD.console { font-family:Courier New; }</STYLE>
  <BODY>
    <j:set var="spc" value="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" />
    <!-- GENERAL INFO -->
    <TABLE>
      <TR>
        <TD align="right">
          <j:choose>
            <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">
              <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/blue.gif" />
            </j:when>
            <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
              <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/red.gif" />
            </j:when>
            <j:otherwise>
              <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/yellow.gif" />
            </j:otherwise>
          </j:choose>
        </TD>
        <TD valign="center">
          <B style="font-size: 200%;">BUILD ${build.result}</B>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Build URL</TD>
        <TD>
          <A href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}</A>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Project:</TD>
        <TD>${project.name}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Date of build:</TD>
        <TD>${it.timestampString}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Build duration:</TD>
        <TD>${build.durationString}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
      <!-- BRANCH -->
        <TD>Subversion Repo:</TD>
        <TD>${build.scm}</TD>
      </TR>
<tr>
          <td>Build Cause:</td>
          <td>
            <j:forEach var="cause" items="${build.causes}">${cause.shortDescription} </j:forEach>
          </td>
  </tr>

    </TABLE>
    <BR />
    <!-- CHANGE SET -->
    <j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" />
    <j:if test="${changeSet!=null}">
      <j:set var="hadChanges" value="false" />
      <TABLE width="100%">
        <TR>
          <TD class="bg1" colspan="2">
            <B>CHANGES</B>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <j:forEach var="cs" items="${changeSet}" varStatus="loop">
          <j:set var="hadChanges" value="true" />
          <j:set var="aUser" value="${cs.hudsonUser}" />
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" class="bg2">${spc}Revision 
            <B>${cs.commitId?:cs.revision?:cs.changeNumber}</B>by 
            <B>${aUser!=null?aUser.displayName:cs.author.displayName}:</B>
            <B>(${cs.msgAnnotated})</B></TD>
          </TR>
          <j:forEach var="p" items="${cs.affectedFiles}">
            <TR>
              <TD width="10%">${spc}${p.editType.name}</TD>
              <TD>${p.path}</TD>
            </TR>
          </j:forEach>
        </j:forEach>
        <j:if test="${!hadChanges}">
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2">No Changes</TD>
          </TR>
        </j:if>
      </TABLE>
      <BR />
    </j:if>
    <!-- ARTIFACTS -->
    <j:set var="artifacts" value="${build.artifacts}" />
    <j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
      <TABLE width="100%">
        <TR>
          <TD class="bg1">
            <B>BUILD ATRIFACTS</B>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>
            <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
              <li>
                <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
              </li>
            </j:forEach>
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
      <BR />
    </j:if>
    <!-- MAVEN ARTIFACTS -->
    <j:set var="mbuilds" value="${build.moduleBuilds}" />
    <j:if test="${mbuilds!=null}">
      <TABLE width="100%">
        <TR>
          <TD class="bg1">
            <B>BUILD ATRIFACTS</B>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <j:forEach var="m" items="${mbuilds}">
          <TR>
            <TD class="bg2">
              <B>${m.key.displayName}</B>
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <j:forEach var="mvnbld" items="${m.value}">
            <j:set var="artifacts" value="${mvnbld.artifacts}" />
            <j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
              <TR>
                <TD>
                  <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
                    <li>
                      <a href="${rooturl}${mvnbld.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
                    </li>
                  </j:forEach>
                </TD>
              </TR>
            </j:if>
          </j:forEach>
        </j:forEach>
      </TABLE>
      <BR />
    </j:if>
    <!-- JUnit TEMPLATE -->
    <j:set var="junitResultList" value="${it.JUnitTestResult}" />
    <j:if test="${junitResultList.isEmpty()!=true}">
      <TABLE width="100%">
        <TR>
          <TD class="bg1" colspan="2">
            <B>${project.name} Functional Tests</B>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <j:forEach var="junitResult" items="${it.JUnitTestResult}">
          <j:forEach var="packageResult" items="${junitResult.getChildren()}">
            <TR>
              <TD class="bg2" colspan="2">Name: ${packageResult.getName()} Failed: ${packageResult.getFailCount()} test(s), Passed: ${packageResult.getP
assCount()} test(s), Skipped: ${packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s), Total:
              ${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s)</TD>
            </TR>
            <j:forEach var="failed_test" items="${packageResult.getFailedTests()}">
              <TR bgcolor="white">
                <TD class="test_failed" colspan="2">
                  <B>
                    <li>Failed: ${failed_test.getFullName()}
                    <br />
                    <pre>
${failed_test.errorDetails}
</pre></li>
                  </B>
                </TD>
              </TR>
              <TR bgcolor="white">
                <TD class="test_failed" colspan="2">
                  <B>
                    <li>StackTrace: ${failed_test.getFullName()}
                    <br />
                    <pre>
${failed_test.errorStackTrace}
</pre></li>
                  </B>
                </TD>
              </TR>
            </j:forEach>
          </j:forEach>
        </j:forEach>
      </TABLE>
      <BR />
    </j:if>
    <!-- COBERTURA TEMPLATE -->
    <j:set var="coberturaAction" value="${it.coberturaAction}" />
    <j:if test="${coberturaAction!=null}">
      <j:set var="coberturaResult" value="${coberturaAction.result}" />
      <j:if test="${coberturaResult!=null}">
        <table width="100%">
          <TD class="bg1" colspan="2">
            <B>Cobertura Report</B>
          </TD>
        </table>
        <table width="100%">
          <TD class="bg2" colspan="2">
            <B>Project Coverage Summary</B>
          </TD>
        </table>
        <table border="1px" class="pane">
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <j:forEach var="metric" items="${coberturaResult.metrics}">
              <td>${metric.name}</td>
            </j:forEach>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>${coberturaResult.name}</td>
            <j:forEach var="metric" items="${coberturaResult.metrics}">
              <td data="${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric).percentageFloat}">${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric).percentage}% (${coberturaResult.ge
tCoverage(metric)})</td>
            </j:forEach>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <j:if test="${coberturaResult.sourceCodeLevel}">
          <h2>Source</h2>
          <j:choose>
            <j:when test="${coberturaResult.sourceFileAvailable}">
              <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
                <table class="source">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">${coberturaResult.relativeSourcePath}</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>${coberturaResult.sourceFileContent}</table>
              </div>
            </j:when>
            <j:otherwise>
              <p>
                <i>Source code is unavailable</i>
              </p>
            </j:otherwise>
          </j:choose>
        </j:if>
        <j:forEach var="element" items="${coberturaResult.childElements}">
          <j:set var="childMetrics" value="${coberturaResult.getChildMetrics(element)}" />
          <table width="100%">
            <TD class="bg2" colspan="2">Coverage Breakdown by ${element.displayName}</TD>
          </table>
          <table border="1px" class="pane sortable">
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <j:forEach var="metric" items="${childMetrics}">
                <td>${metric.name}</td>
              </j:forEach>
            </tr>
            <j:forEach var="c" items="${coberturaResult.children}">
              <j:set var="child" value="${coberturaResult.getChild(c)}" />
              <tr>
                <td>${child.xmlTransform(child.name)}</td>
                <j:forEach var="metric" items="${childMetrics}">
                  <j:set var="childResult" value="${child.getCoverage(metric)}" />
                  <j:choose>
                    <j:when test="${childResult!=null}">
                      <td data="${childResult.percentageFloat}">${childResult.percentage}% (${childResult})</td>
                    </j:when>
                    <j:otherwise>
                      <td data="101">N/A</td>
                    </j:otherwise>
                  </j:choose>
                </j:forEach>
              </tr>
            </j:forEach>
          </table>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:if>
      <BR />
    </j:if>
 <!-- HEALTH TEMPLATE -->
    <div class="content">
      <j:set var="healthIconSize" value="16x16" />
      <j:set var="healthReports" value="${project.buildHealthReports}" />
      <j:if test="${healthReports!=null}">
        <h1>Health Report</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>W</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Score</th>
          </tr>
          <j:forEach var="healthReport" items="${healthReports}">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="${rooturl}${healthReport.getIconUrl(healthIconSize)}" />
              </td>
              <td>${healthReport.description}</td>
              <td>${healthReport.score}</td>
            </tr>
          </j:forEach>
        </table>
        <br />
      </j:if>
    </div>
    <!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->
    <j:getStatic var="resultFailure" field="FAILURE" className="hudson.model.Result" />
    <j:if test="${build.result==resultFailure}">
      <TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <TR>
          <TD class="bg1">
            <B>CONSOLE OUTPUT</B>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <j:forEach var="line" items="${build.getLog(100)}">
          <TR>
            <TD class="console">${line}</TD>
          </TR>
        </j:forEach>
      </TABLE>
      <BR />
    </j:if>
  </BODY>
</j:jelly>



 <!-- BRANCH -->
            <TD>Subversion Repo:</TD>
            <TD>${build.scm}</TD>
          </TR>
```

does not work, and i am not sure which argument to use with build object to get subversion url.

outside jelly script, i can get the Subversion URL, using:
Subversion URL: ${ENV, var="SVN_URL"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <TD>${build.envVars.SVN_URL}</TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work -

```
<j:set var="buildenv" value="${build.getEnvironment(listener)}"/> 
<j:set var="myvar" value="${buildenv.get('SVN_URL')}"/>
```

Reference: [Jelly script for ext-email plugin jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817402/jelly-script-for-ext-email-plugin-jenkins)

Comment: tried: as.
<TD>Subversion Repo:</TD>
        <TD>
        <j:set var="buildenv" value="${build.getEnvironment(listener)}"/>
        <j:set var="myvar" value="${buildenv.get('SVN_URL')}"/>
        </TD>
      </TR>
still no svn repo url in email.